# How troubleshoot bad request in Application Insights of Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am receiving more tan 10.000 bad request in Application Insights of Azure, I know some details of the transaction but I can not find a thread to pull, and understand why those head requests are getting a 404 error, how can I troubleshoot those requests?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be resolved by making a valid "/" path in you application that returns a 200 response. Alternatively look at @RithwikBojja-MT refs.

The reason for this is actually that Azure pings the root path of your applications if you have the "Always-On" feature enabled.